# Criar pasta/diretório com Node.JS

Tags: node.js

Existe o módulo "fs", que é utilizado para criação de arquivos:

```
const fs = require("fs");
fs.writeFile(`./teste.txt`, "conteúdo",
        function (erro) {
            if (erro) {
                throw erro;
            }
            console.log("Arquivo salvo com sucesso!");
        });
```

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira que eu possa criar um diretório de forma parecida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existem alguns métodos dentro da `fs` que permitem a criação da diretórios, um deles é o `mkdirSync`, exemplo:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dir = "C:/Temp/Xisto";

//Verifica se não existe
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    //Efetua a criação do diretório
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}
```

Como o próprio nome já diz, trata-se de um método síncrono.

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/UnrulyOrangeBit

---

Existe também a `mkdir`, tendo como diferença ser assíncrona:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dir = "C:/Temp/Xisto";

//Verifica se não existe
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    //Efetua a criação do diretório
    fs.mkdir(dir, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Deu ruim...");
            return
        }

        console.log("Diretório criado! =)")
    });
}
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/PoliteDownrightTrial

---

> Referência: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html